# Git Hook for git pull

Tags: git, githooks

I am trying to write a git hook after we run git pull, irrespective of whether there is a change or not. The `post-merge` was the only one which does that, but it does in case if there is a merge. 
Any ideas ?

Comment: Could you clarify your use case? It seems that what you are looking to do is outside the applicable scope of git hooks (and git in general), but if you can give a better idea of what you want the hook to do, maybe there are alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like there are no hooks that run on a pull unconditionally.

How about adding a git alias to do a pull+ ?

If you don't want to use a new name (I think git commands cannot be overridden using git alias), you could use a shell alias.