# What Git hook is invoked when changes are pulled into an empty repository?

Tags: git, automation, githooks

I'm trying to understand how to work with Git local hooks.

My goal is to compare the current state of the branch with received updates, and then execute some shell command if a certain file was changed.

I'm using `git diff-tree` command to get the difference.

I have no problem with `post-checkout` hook. As far as I understand, `post-checkout` hook invokes when a repository is cloned or a branch is switched. I need it only for cloning, and it works fine.

But `post-merge` hook is triggered only if the repository already contains some files. If I clone an empty repository, then push some files to the origin and pull changes into the cloned repository, the hook is simply ignored.

But I don't know in advance whether a cloned repository will be empty or will contain some files, so I need to handle both cases.

Is there a specific Git hook that will work when changes are pulled into an empty repository, or I should handle the problem in some other way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26772794/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgithooks%5D+pull

Comment: There are new *reference transaction* hooks in Git 2.28 and later; these will be invoked if at least one ref name (branch name, tag name, etc) is created, deleted, or updated.

Comment: @phd Thank you, but it seems it isn't what I need. Topic starter was looking for a solution that works irrespective of changes in a repository, and the answers do not contain any solutions.

Comment: @torek Thank you. I tried `reference-transaction` hook with Git 2.28, and it is triggered when I download changes into an empty repository. Unfortunately I can't find any example of usage of this hook, but I'll try to play with it.

Comment: @ivanov17 "*…the answers do not contain any solutions.*" Sometimes "No way" is the answer.